# Selenium Child process - module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, child-process

I have an Error in my `Angular` `Selenium` Child process. The error is as follows:

```sh
./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

check all imports for 'selenium-webdriver' e.g httpclient, eventEmitter and make sure they are not imported from selenium-webdriver.